# No module named 'pysnmp.smi'; 'pysnmp' is not a package

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I've been working on pysnmp agent and downloaded a script from here:
https://pypi.org/project/snmp-agent/#description . And I can't get it working. When I try to run its python script, this is what I got

```
PS C:\Users\#######\Documents\VSCode\python\snmplib> python pysnmp.py      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\YENS_User2\Documents\VSCode\python\snmplib\pysnmp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pysnmp.smi import builder
  File "C:\Users\YENS_User2\Documents\VSCode\python\snmplib\pysnmp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pysnmp.smi import builder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysnmp.smi'; 'pysnmp' is not a package
PS C:\Users\#######\Documents\VSCode\python\snmplib>
```

which is pertaining to this import
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjfSH.png)

```
|1| from pysnmp.smi import builder
|2| from pysnmp.smi import instrum
|3| from pysnmp.smi import exval
|4| from pysnmp.smi import error
```

I also download the package needed for this. Here is my pip list

```
Package       Version
------------- -------
asn1          2.7.0
click         8.1.3
colorama      0.4.6
enum-compat   0.0.3
Flask         2.2.3
itsdangerous  2.1.2
Jinja2        3.1.2
MarkupSafe    2.1.2
pip           22.2.2
ply           3.11
pyasn1        0.4.8
pycryptodomex 3.17
pysmi         0.3.4
pysnmp-mibs   0.1.6
setuptools    63.2.0
snmp-agent    0.2.3
Werkzeug      2.2.3
```

My Python version is `Python 3.10.8`

I wish anyone could help me.

Comment: This is in fact a "typo" level issue. You named your test script `pysnmp.py` so any type resolution used this file as context, and the error message came from here. Try to name it as `test-pysnmp.py` and I believe the error will go away.